# Running gsutil on MacOS

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, gsutil

I am trying to use gsutil to set CORS on my firebase storage bucket according to googles instructions using the newest version of MacOS. I am not sure if I havn't installed gsutil correctly or if the is something else I don't understand, but when I run `gsutil cors set cors.json gs://docavea2.appspot.com` I get the following error:

```
Setting CORS on gs://docavea2.appspot.com/...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jr/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__init__.py", line 119, in <module>
    CHECKSUM_FILE, CHECKSUM = _GetFileContents('CHECKSUM')
  File "/Users/jr/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__init__.py", line 107, in _GetFileContents
    content = pkgutil.get_data('gslib', filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 591, in get_data
    return loader.get_data(resource_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 255, in get_data
    return open(pathname, "rb").read()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/jr/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/CHECKSUM'
```

I think my cors.json is fine, because when I use it with gsutil on Windows it works fine and CORS is set correctly, but this is the content:

```
[
    {
        "origin": ["*"],
        "method": ["GET"],
        "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

I have seen here on stackoverflow that somebody said that it worked for him if he put [{ on the same line, but it makes no difference for me.

Comment: This is a pkgutil issue, not a problem with your CORS file. Does /Users/jr/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/CHECKSUM actually exist on your system?

Answer (score 8):

I found out CHECKSUM is installed in 
/Users/jr/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil.

After I copy it to 
/Users/jr/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/ it works.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was re-installing google-cloud-sdk into my home directory (Users/sam/google-cloud-sdk). It was in the downloads folder.